# View3DOverlay.show_overlays exists in context only?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

If I use the following code in a workspace with a View 3D, I can see its property `show_overlays` in Python:

```py
area = next(area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == 'VIEW_3D')
space = next(space for space in area.spaces if space.type == 'VIEW_3D')
print(space.overlay.show_overlays)
```

The overlay is of class type `View3DOverlay`. In the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.View3DOverlay.html#bpy.types.View3DOverlay.show_overlays), it says `show_overlay` is one of its many properties, however this code throws an `AttributeError`:

```
print(bpy.types.View3DOverlay.show_overlays)
```

`show_overlays` and all of the other properties also do not show when using autocomplete in the Python console. Do these properties only exist in the Context? I'm very confused.

Thank you!

Comment: `bpy.types.View3DOverlay` is a class that has the member variable `show_overlays`. you cannot access it directly through the class. `space.overlay` on the other hand contains an instance of the class `bpy.types.View3DOverlay`. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_classes.asp

Comment: Thank you @HarryMcKenzie!